# What are 'Latch' and 'Pulse' in reactive-banana?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

Do the [Latch](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Prim.html#g:8) and [Pulse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Prim.html#g:7) types exist in FRP literature, or are they an invention of the author of reactive-banana?

Just looking at the types, they roughly correspond to Behavior and Event (respectively), but I'd like to know what the difference is, and whether their implementation is based on any formal research.

Thank you!

Comment: This looks a lot like a recommendation for a resource (off-topic). Perhaps rephrase as "does <specific author> recognize these FRP concepts?" or "here is my understanding of the semantics of Latch and Pulse - is this understanding correct?"

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks, I didn't know recommendations for resources are off-topic. I tried to clarify the question by giving some more context.

Comment: "[Reactive.Banana.Prim](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana/src/Reactive/Banana/Prim.hs) - The efficient push-driven implementation used for production code. Contains hard to understand trade secrets. ;-)". Here's to hoping [@heinrich-apfelmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403805/heinrich-apfelmus) can elaborate more here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heinrich here. The `Pulse` and `Latch` types are probably best seen as "lemmas" that I came up with that are very useful for implementing the `Event` and `Behavior` type. I'm sure that they will prove useful when trying to justify the implementation more formally, but this is a formidable research project, and I have not found the time or resources to do so.

The type `Pulse` is almost the same as `Event`, except that all functions are required to have a monadic type, e.g.

```
mapP :: (a → b) → Pulse a → Build (Pulse b)
-- vs
mapE :: (a → b) → Event a → Event b
```

The `Event` type is implemented by getting rid of the `Build` monad via black magic (= observable sharing). The name `Build` sounds like it's a utility monad, which it is if you look at the code, but this monad is also fundamental, because it has a semantic interpretation as "moment of time", and it's not obvious why you can remove it sometimes, and sometimes not.

The type `Latch` is also very similar to `Behavior`, except that the latter also includes an `Event` for pragmatic reasons. Similar considerations apply concerning the `Build` monad.

I hope this answers more questions than it raises.  Sorry that I couldn't go into more detail as for the inner workings of reactive-banana, that would be beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.